# import error no module named cmd.manage

Tags: cloud, openstack, devstack, keystone

Am getting the above error while installing the keystone and python-keystoneclient. It is blocking me from installing and configuring the openstack devstack. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just uninstalled the python-keystoneclient completely and reinstalled it. It works now.